# two versions of PHP on the same Ubuntu 18.04 server with Apache

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-18.04, fpm

I have a server with Ubuntu 18.04 on which I host two applications, one works with PHP 7.0 and the other with PHP 8.0. I have followed several guides where they explain in detail what to do with PHP-FPM and I do all the steps correctly without throwing errors but when checking in the browser it shows me version 8.0 for both. Could you help me with this?” Is there anything else you would like to know?

these are the virtual hosts

```
<VirtualHost *80:>
    ServerName certificacion.local
    DocumentRoot /var/www/certificacion.local

    <Directory /var/www/certificacion.local>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$" "unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/var/www/certificacion.local"

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/certificacion.local-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/certificacion.local-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName fiscalizacion.local
    DocumentRoot /var/www/fiscalizacion.local

    <Directory /var/www/fiscalizacion.local>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$" "unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/var/www/fiscalizacion.local"

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/fiscalizacion.local-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/fiscalizacion.local-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>`
```

i tried to configure PHP-FPM

Comment: maybe the fpm config does not distinguish between php versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how it works for me

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/qa-laravel/public"
        ServerName .....local
        <Directory "/var/www/qa-laravel/public">
                AllowOverride All
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
             <FilesMatch \.php$>
                    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhos>
            </FilesMatch>
    
    </VirtualHost>
```

Check PHP-FPM service: Confirm that the PHP-FPM services for both PHP versions are running properly.

```
 service php7.0-fpm status
 service php8.0-fpm status
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the support, however I chose to reinstall Ubuntu and start from scratch because before discovering the PHP-FPM function I tried thousands of things, I suppose something was configured to default to version 8.0.

I just followed the steps from this link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-multiple-php-versions-on-one-server-using-apache-and-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-18-04 and everything worked correctly. I hope it can help someone else! Greetings.